# Issue with Intel 3000 Driver and Windows 10 on Macbook Air

Tags: boot-camp, windows-10-preview, macbook-air, display-driver

I have installed Windows 10 Technical Preview (10162). The installation went fine but after the installation, windows installs the Intel HD 3000 driver trough windows update and after that, the screens stays black. When I reboot the computer, I see the windows loading screen, but afterwards the screens turns black and stays like this (I imagine that this is when the driver gets loaded). 
I tried to disable the automatic driver updates, but windows still downloads this drivers and I end up in the same situation.

I have also tried to install the drivers from the [bootcamp support software (5.1.4650)](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1721?locale=de_CH) with the exact same result. I imagine that this is an incompatibility between Windows 10 and this driver.

I haven't found a way to disable that update or a way to boot directly into recovery mode and uninstall the driver.
Any ideas on how I could prevent windows from installing that driver?

Comment: You will have to wait until Intel releases drivers compatible with Windows 10, you can also wait, until Bootcamp officially supports Windows 10.  [Beta Drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25027/Intel-Iris-Iris-Pro-and-HD-Graphics-Beta-Driver-for-Windows-10)

Comment: But I don't really need the driver, everything works fine without it. What I am looking for, is a way to prevent Windows from installing it and stick to the default driver (the one that comes installed with Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue in the following blogpost: http://hmemcpy.com/2015/04/preventing-a-certain-windows-update-from-installing-on-windows-10/

It describes how to disable a certain update in Windows 10 Technical Preview, here is short wrap up of the required steps, for the full guide, refer to the blog.

**Install Windows Powershell Update Module**

The module contains a set of functions to interact with the Windows Update from powershell.

- First you need to download the [Windows Update Powershell Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc) and extract it to  `%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` (or  `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`)
- To install it, set the execution policy to unrestricted (run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force` from powershell as admin) and import the module (`Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate`). After that, you should reset the execution policy to something more restrictive, such as `RemoteSigned`

**Disable the Intel driver update**

- Get the list of updates to be installed: `Get-WUList`. This will print a list of all updates which will be installed.
- To disable the Intel driver, use the `Hide-WUUpdate` function, e.g `Hide-WUUpdate -Title "Intel*"` (it might match multiple updates, but it will prompt you for every match, if you want to disable it or not).
- If you re-run `Get-WUList`, the Intel driver has an *H* under *Status*, this means that it is hidden and won't be installed.